# Are there private IPv4 ranges AWS reserves for its use?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, private-subnet

When we create a VPC, we generally allocate it a private IPv4 address range as specified in [RFC 1918](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1918.html).

I am making an assumption that Internet Gateway, NAT Gateway etc. are hosted on AWS managed VPCs as they are highly available and scalable same like how a customer would design a service on AWS.

**Are there private IPv4 ranges AWS reserves for its use to solve overlaps between Customer's VPC and their own VPCs that hosts Internet Gateway / NAT Gateway? How is the CIDR overlaps managed?**

Comment: Can you focus on one question, rather then asking multiple subquestions?

Comment: @Marcin - shortened now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are asking about overlaps between customer VPCs and the actual networks used to 'run' AWS. However, there is no such overlap.

All networking in VPCs is virtual. Infrastructure deployed within VPCs are given IP addresses from the VPC's CIDR range. For example, a NAT Gateway connects to a VPC via an Elastic Network Interface (ENI), which consumes a private IP address from within the VPC. This allows it to communicate with other resources in the VPC, such as EC2 instances, RDS databases and Load Balancers.

The Internet Gateway does *not* consume any private IP addresses. It is simply a routing concept between a VPC and the Internet.

The actual equipment that AWS uses to operate services runs on separate networks that exist 'outside of' VPCs.

Comment: yes, this is what I was looking for - I thought all Gateways i.e. IGW, NAT GW etc. were having a common mechanism - seems not because NAT GW is powered by a compute node whereas IGW is just a routing concept - Naming pitfalls I'd say - Thank you.

Comment: Had a separate question on similar lines - how would AWS manage overlaps between a customer VPC and a service AWS offers when both are connected via PrivateLink i.e. using interface endpoints? Is there NAT techniques AWS might be using? @John Rotenstein

Comment: Interface endpoints consume a private IP address within the VPC. This is how traffic accesses the services 'outside' of the VPC.

Comment: correct - a compute node (possibly managed by AWS) that's associated with the private IP in Customer VPC might be doing NAT to avoid conflicts with the AWS service VPC when using interface endpoints?@John Rotenstein

Comment: @AbhishekPalakkalKaliyath All networking in AWS is "virtual networking" via encapsulated packets. The networking traffic does not run on 'real' networks, so there is no address conflicts. None of this is relevant for users of AWS -- it simply works as requested, with no need to worry about such conflicts. For example, you can create multiple VPCs with identical address ranges and they all work. There is no need to concern yourself about implementation details. It's like somebody asking Dell whether they should worry about voltages between CPU pins on their computer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are some ways AWS reserves ip addresses in your VPC :).

1. Firstly, the internet gateway actually does not use up an address in your VPC. The vpc router basically takes care of routes to the internet gateway (more on the vpc router below). I guess that they use all kinds of fancy network overlays and tricks to handle this traffic. Unfortunately I'm not enough of a network specialist to know the exact tech they use for this.
2. When creating a NAT gateway, AWS actually creates an elastic network interface inside your subnet with a a private ip address attached to it. You can see these when going to the 'elastic network interface' view in the EC2 console. Obviously, you can't reuse these addresses.
3. Thirdly, aws actually reserves several addresses per subnet. From the aws docs:

> The first four IP addresses and the last IP address in each subnet CIDR block are not available for you to use, and cannot be assigned to an instance. For example, in a subnet with CIDR block 10.0.0.0/24, the following five IP addresses are reserved:
>
> - 10.0.0.0: Network address.
> - 10.0.0.1: Reserved by AWS for the VPC router.
> - 10.0.0.2: Reserved by AWS. The IP address of the DNS server is the base of the VPC network range plus two. For VPCs with multiple CIDR blocks, the IP address of the DNS server is located in the primary CIDR. We also reserve the base of each subnet range plus two for all CIDR blocks in the VPC. For more information, see Amazon DNS server.
> - 10.0.0.3: Reserved by AWS for future use.
> - 10.0.0.255: Network broadcast address. We do not support broadcast in a VPC, therefore we reserve this address.
>   If you create a VPC or subnet using a command line tool or the Amazon EC2 API, the CIDR block is automatically modified to its canonical form. For example, if you specify 100.68.0.18/18 for the CIDR block, we create a CIDR block of 100.68.0.0/18.

So in short, the vpc router takes care of routing requests to AWS internet gateway, NAT gateways get their own elastic network interface and there are some other addresses reserved as well.

Answer (score 0):

Private IP address can reuse in different network and can not be use in public, that's why it is called private.

If you use AWS services and if it is in a VPC, it will get an IP address in your CIDR range. Otherwise, it will allocate in AWS network.